# React Native and Azure Active Directory

Tags: react-native, azure-active-directory

I've found no library for Azure Active Directory/ADAL for React Native. Could anyone give me a hint how to go about implementing ADAL with React Native?

Comment: Try [react-native-azure-ad](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-azure-ad)